# Correct Way of using USART on PIC 16

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart

I am trying to recieve 1 character using the USART feature on PIC 16.

Both the transmitter and receiver are both PIC 16s.

Can i check if the way to call the receive function is correct conceptually

```
char tmp;

CREN = 0;
CREN = 1;

while(!RCIF); 

if(OERR==1)
{
  tmp = RCREG;
  tmp = RCREG;
  CREN=0;
  DelayMs(5);
  CREN=1;
}
else
{
 tmp = RCREG;
}

CREN = 0;
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You must first initiate the UART.

1. Load into SPBRG register proper
   number depend on your **baud
   rate** and CPU clock frequency
   (check datasheet).
2. Set BRGH bit in register TXSTA depend on desired baud rate generator (check datasheet).
3. Set bits in RCSTA register depend on data length and so on (check datasheet). Enable CREN bit in RCSTA register.
4. Wait on PIR1.RCIF == 1 bit which indicate that buffer receiver is full (only one byte).